# javascript not accepting boolean or null from php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to learn javascript. I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $a = true;
    $b = false;
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.variable = {
            a: <?php $a ? true : false ?>,
            b: <?php $b ? 1 : null ?>
        }

        console.log(variable);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript is not accepting the `true`, `fasle`, `1` or `null`
I am getting the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,` and it is displaying the following in the chrome dev tools:

```
<script>
    window.variable = {
    a: ,
    b:      }

    console.log(variable);
</script>
```

where am I going wrong??

Comment: You have to echo the value.

Comment: You need your PHP variables to be json_encoded, E.G `a: <?php echo json_encode($a) ? true : false; ?>,`

Comment: the `<?php ...?>` tag is for executing php only. It do not output anything to the document. You need to use [echo or <?=php ...?>](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.echo.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a: <?php $a ? true : false ?>,
b: <?php $b ? 1 : null ?>
```

First, you're not *outputting* anything. You need to `echo` things.

Second, the string representation of `false` is an empty string. Same thing for `null`. So, even with `echo`, you'll get empty outputs for some values of `$a` and `$b`, and the same JS syntax error.

You can fix the output by outputting the *strings* true, false, and null:

```
a: <?php echo $a ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
b: <?php echo $b ? 1 : 'null' ?>
```

but for a more resilient approach, since you're outputting for use in JavaScript, use `json_encode` instead:

```
a: <?php echo json_encode($a ? true : false) ?>,
b: <?php echo json_encode($b ? 1 : null) ?>
```

or, even better, have PHP output the whole JS object:

```
window.variable = <?php echo json_encode([
    'a' => $a ? true : false,
    'b' => $b ? 1 : null,
]); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you're building text; use "echo" to output the right value as a string.

```
<?php
  $a = true;
  $b = false;
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.variable = {
            a: <?php echo $a ? "true" : "false" ?>,
            b: <?php echo $b ? "1" : "null" ?>
        }

        console.log(variable);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```